# How to write HQL expression in Hadoop to verify format of alphanumeric field in specific format such as X9999

Tags: hadoop, hql, impala, hue

How do I write HQL to determine if results from a field have 1st character as alpha and the following four are numeric.  (i.e. - the format of the field is 'F5555', so I need to verify all the results returned from the query for this field are following the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( 'd55555' , '^[A-Za-z ]?[0-9]{5}$', 0);
```

Now, in order to understand, please read [this](http://psoug.org/snippet.htm/Regular_Expressions_Regex_Cheat_Sheet_856.htm?PHPSESSID=7238be874ab99d0731a9da64f2dbafd8) and see the next comments:

- ^ means the beginning of the string(in this mode we mark the beginning);
- [A-Za-z] - means any letter: upper or lower case;
- ? - means that we want only 1 occurrence of the previous character class;
- [0-9] - any digit from 0 to 9;
- {5} - means that the previous character class ([0-9]) must appear 5 times exactly (no more, no less);
- $ - end of the string;

Hope that you understood.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!